# Parse error syntax error after Wordpress update

Tags: vagrant

After updating Wordpress to 5.3.2, on VVV environment I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /srv/www/woo/public_html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 413

The interesting part is that the file has only 411 lines.

The file is included in wp-settings.php. When I do error_log before it's inclusion it prints fine, but when I put error_log after it doesn't show the message which proves the PHP parser see the error in default-constants.php file.

I tried to disable all the plugins and comment my entire child-theme/functions.php, no result.

On VVV I use php-fpm7.3 and nginx 1.17.3.

Any idea how to solve it?
How can the parser complain about the line that doens't exists?

Answer (score 1):

It turn out to be the kernel bug in VVV -> https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/1819.

Halting and restarting vagrant solves the problem. The ultimate solution is to upgrade VVV to current version.